# Azure DevOps Repos section not visible despite correct permissions

Tags: azure, azure-devops

The Repos section of the Azure DevOps dashboard is not visible to me, what could the reason for this be?

Under my user account's permissions profile, "**View project-level information**" is set to "Allow (inherit)".

There is another team member with an identical set of permissions that can view the Repos section as well, which leads me to believe it's not a permissions issue.

[image: What I see]

Is there a configuration I'm missing? I can't find anything online about it.

Comment: Check your access level. Are you a Stakeholder? Stakeholders do not have access to repos. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops

Comment: AHHHH Thanks I am indeed a Stakeholder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was my access was at the stakeholder level rather than basic+.

Comment: Mine was that as well. Switched to basic+ and got access to Repos and Wiki.

Comment: Step1: Go to Azure DevOps Organization Settings 

Step2: Click on Users and Search for the user for whom the access level should be changed.

REF:  
https://www.azuredevopsguide.com/change-user-access-from-stakeholder-to-basic-azure-devops/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Repos service enabled on the Project settings overview screen. It is disabled on the below example:

[image]

Comment: The service is set to On, I think it's because I'm a stakeholder at the organisation level...looking into getting it changed to see if it works before closing thread. Thanks for reply though